# Macro to loop through all sheets that are placed between two named sheets and copy their data to a consolidated file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template file which will be sent out to all subsidiaries of my company.

1. The template has a tab named *start* and one named *end*.
2. The subsidiaries will place a variable number of template submission sheets between these two names sheets and send them in to me to consolidate into one sheet in my consolidation file.
3. I have written macros to copy each sheet into the consolidation file, but I currently need to run it sheet by sheet as I don't know how to loop.
4. The copy macro sits in my Personal.xls file and the paste macro sits in the consolidation sheet.
5. The loop macro would need to work between the *Source file* (could be any name) and the consolidation file which is called *Consolidation.xls*.
6. Once all sheets are copied from a source file, I then open the next source file and start again, so macro would need to forget the old source file and remember the new one.

This could literally save me hours each week if I could get a macro to work, so any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to loop through all sheets including start and end?

Comment: All sheets that are placed between the start and end tabs, but not the start or end itself. The start and end tabs themselves are blank.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is along the lines of what you are chasing. If all your templates are in a **single folder**, and each have a "start" and "end" sheet then this code will collate them into either

- A new workbook with a unique sheet for each relevant sheet in each template
- Into a single sheet in a new workbook

I have updated my code from "Collating worksheets from one or more workbooks into a summary file", http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2804.html to cater for your "start" and "end" sheets

Please post if you need (or have) further detail

```
Public Sub ConsolidateSheets()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim lrowSpace As Long
    Dim lSht As Long
    Dim lngCalc As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim X()
    Dim bProcessFolder As Boolean
    Dim bNewSheet As Boolean

    Dim StrPrefix
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolderName As String

    'variant declaration needed for the Shell object to use a default directory
    Dim strDefaultFolder As Variant


 bProcessFolder = (MsgBox("Process a single folder (Yes)," & vbNewLine & "or single file (No)", vbYesNo, "Application Scope: Folder or single File") = vbYes)
    bNewSheet = (MsgBox("Extract all data to a single sheet (Yes)," & vbNewLine & "or a target file sheet for each source sheet (No)", vbYesNo, "Output Format: Single sheet or sheet by sheet collection") = vbYes)
    If Not bProcessFolder Then
        If Not bNewSheet Then
            MsgBox "There isn't much point creating a exact replica of your source file :)"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    'set default directory here if needed
    strDefaultFolder = "C:\"

    'If the user is collating all the sheets to a single target sheet then the row spacing
    'to distinguish between different sheets can be set here
    lrowSpace = 1

    If bProcessFolder Then
        strFolderName = BrowseForFolder(strDefaultFolder)
        'Look for xls, xlsx, xlsm files
        strFileName = Dir(strFolderName & "\*.xls*")
    Else
        strFileName = Application _
                      .GetOpenFilename("Select file to process (*.xls*), *.xls*")
    End If

    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Add(1)
    Set ws1 = Wb1.Sheets(1)
    If Not bNewSheet Then ws1.Range("A1:B1") = Array("workbook name", "worksheet count")

    'Turn off screenupdating, events, alerts and set calculation to manual
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        lngCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'set path outside the loop
    StrPrefix = strFolderName & IIf(bProcessFolder, "\", vbNullString)

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        'Provide progress status to user
        Application.StatusBar = Left("Processing " & strFolderName & "\" & strFileName, 255)
        'Open each workbook in the folder of interest
        Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(StrPrefix & strFileName)
        If Not bNewSheet Then
            'add summary details to first sheet
            ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Wb2.Name
            ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = Wb2.Sheets.Count
        End If
        For Each ws2 In Wb2.Sheets
        If ws2.Index > Wb2.Sheets("start").Index And ws2.Index < Wb2.Sheets("end").Index Then
            If bNewSheet Then
                'All data to a single sheet
                'Skip importing target sheet data if the source sheet is blank
                Set rng2 = ws2.Cells.Find("*", ws2.[a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

                If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng1 = ws1.Cells.Find("*", ws1.[a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
                    'Find the first blank row on the target sheet
                    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng3 = ws2.Range(ws2.UsedRange.Cells(1), ws2.Cells(rng2.Row, "A"))
                        'Ensure that the row area in the target sheet won't be exceeded
                        If rng3.Rows.Count + rng1.Row < Rows.Count Then
                            'Copy the data from the used range of each source sheet to the first blank row
                            'of the target sheet, using the starting column address from the source sheet being copied
                            ws2.UsedRange.Copy ws1.Cells(rng1.Row + 1 + lrowSpace, ws2.UsedRange.Cells(1).Column)
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Summary sheet size exceeded. Process stopped on " & vbNewLine & _
                                   "sheet: " & ws2.Name & vbNewLine & "of" & vbNewLine & "workbook: " & Wb2.Name
                            Wb2.Close False
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                        'colour the first of any spacer rows
                        If lrowSpace <> 0 Then ws1.Rows(rng1.Row + 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                    Else
                        'target sheet is empty so copy to first row
                        ws2.UsedRange.Copy ws1.Cells(1, ws2.UsedRange.Cells(1).Column)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                'new target sheet for each source sheet
                ws2.Copy after:=Wb1.Sheets(Wb1.Sheets.Count)
                'Remove any links in our target sheet
                With Wb1.Sheets(Wb1.Sheets.Count).Cells
                    .Copy
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
                On Error Resume Next
                Wb1.Sheets(Wb1.Sheets.Count).Name = ws2.Name
                'sheet name already exists in target workbook
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    'Add a number to the sheet name till a unique name is derived
                    Do
                        lSht = lSht + 1
                        Set ws3 = Wb1.Sheets(ws2.Name & " " & lSht)
                    Loop While Not ws3 Is Nothing
                    lSht = 0
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            End If
        Next ws2
        'Close the opened workbook
        Wb2.Close False
        'Check whether to force a DO loop exit if processing a single file
        If bProcessFolder = False Then Exit Do
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

    'Remove any links if the user has used a target sheet
    If bNewSheet Then
        With ws1.UsedRange
            .Copy
            .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(1).Activate
        End With
    Else
        'Format the summary sheet if the user has created separate target sheets
        ws1.Activate
        ws1.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
        ws1.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lngCalc
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
End Sub


Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
'From Ken Puls as used in his vbaexpress.com article
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=284

    Dim ShellApp As Object
    'Create a file browser window at the default folder
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
                   BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    'Set the folder to that selected.  (On error in case cancelled)
    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Destroy the Shell Application
    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    'Check for invalid or non-entries and send to the Invalid error
    'handler if found
    'Valid selections can begin L: (where L is a letter) or
    '\\ (as in \\servername\sharename.  All others are invalid
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function

Invalid:
    'If it was determined that the selection was invalid, set to False
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

Comment: Brettdj, Hands down that is the most amazing thing I have seen in VBA. I just changed the default directory and it worked perfectly. Full credit to you for taking a written request (with no example vba code) and turning it into a completely working macro. I am extremely grateful, thankyou.

Comment: brettdj, I followed your guidance on experts exchange to select just one sheet from each "source" file. However the source sheet I need to copy has a number of Macro buttons in the first 7 rows of the sheet which are not required in the summary. I modified the macro using your guidance to delete the rows as if they were a header, but this solution doesn't work well as the macro buttons in those rows are not deleted, just the rows are. Is there a way to modify the range of the cells being copied from the source file, perhaps so that the used range starts at row 8?

Answer (score 0):

You should show us some code if you really want help.

But as far as I understood your question, here are some tips or links.

**Code snippet to loop over worksheets**

```
Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open("C:\bookB.xls")

For Each ws In wkbkorigin.Worksheets  
    'do whatever
Next
```

**Some stackoverflow threads about this issue**

- [excel vba loop through worksheets and set values according to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300953/excel-vba-loop-through-worksheets-and-set-values-according-to-input)
- [How can I loop through a subset of worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591442/excel-vba-how-to-loop-through-a-subset-of-worksheets)

**Some more tips about getting info from files**

See this valuable thread: [Copy data from another Workbook through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401967/copy-data-from-another-workbook-through-vba/)

You will find info about:

- [how to use the Excel object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401967/copy-data-from-another-workbook-through-vba/7402165#7402165) to copy data from a file to another
- using [GetInfoFromClosedFile()](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Read_information_from_a_closed_workbook_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/473.html) function

Answer (score 0):

Once you've defined workbooks/worksheets as per JMax response, I think you're looking for the following...

```
 IncludeSheet=0

 For n = 1 to wkbkOrigin.Worksheets.Count
     If wkbkOrigin.Sheets(n).Name = "End" Then
     IncludeSheet = 0
     End If
     If IncludeSheet = 1 Then
          Set ws = wkbkOrigin.Sheets(n)

     'do whatever
     End If
     If wkbkOrigin.Sheets(n).Name = "Start" Then
     IncludeSheet = 1
     End If
 Next n
```

The key is to introduce a flag variable to tell you if you're in the right part of the workbook, in this case IncludeSheet