# Writing from one instance of Excel to another open instance

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a workbook to display operator data. This work book is always open and needs to stay open. Im trying to open a different instance of excel and have it write and update values on the open display workbook. The path to the workbook is G:\TLS-Shared\Maintenance\POWDER LINE DISPLAY\input.xlsm and the always open workbook is G:\TLS-Shared\Maintenance\POWDER LINE DISPLAY\display.xlsm I need to transfer 7 columns, 30 rows of each column from input.xlms sheet name "data" to the open book sheet name DisplayData. I will need this to regularly update or click a button to update.

Comment: This situation is covered many times here at SO. One possible reference <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310458/how-to-copy-data-from-closed-workbookskeeping-them-closed-into-master-workbook>. It is expected here that some homework is done before asking question.

Comment: thank you but thats not at all what im looking for, one book in one instance is constantly open and needs to stay open, i need to write to the open book and have it update without closing and reopening, as far as homework before asking a question, did mine... did you?

Comment: It is not any thing special. When we are working one instance can remain open all the time. It needs to be saved only after a change in data. Other instance you are opening for transferring data. It can be in the same instance or a new instance of excel. Off hand I may not be remembering, but I have come across it in  a no of cases when a new instance of excel has been opened may be for different purpose.I may be wrong but go by my peers opinion in this case. Let them take the corrective action.

Comment: Why do you need to open a different instance of Excel ?  Why not work within the existing instance?

Comment: i need two different instances, one instance is displaying data to the floor the second instance on a different machine is to manually edit parts of the data being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the data from the input workbook  and then in the display workbook (has to be in the same Excel instance) click Paste > Paste Link

[image: https://computertrainer.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/paste-paste-link.png]

Now in the Data tab you can click Refresh all to update the data when needed

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHFpd.jpg]

You can also change the connection property to refresh every minute:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kdcx.png]

Works even if the input workbook is closed.

Comment: Thank you but has I said I need two different instances, eg.
 one instance is displaying data to the floor the second instance on a different machine is to manually edit parts of the data being displayed

Comment: This should work if the input.xlsm file is saved after the changes are made.  I suggest trying it and comment on what part did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Can you simply record a Macro to do most of what you want and modify it a bit?  That should pretty much do it.