# VBA copy data from other workbook in ".csv" file Format

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have this code to copy data from other closed workbook in excel.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim DTLBranchValue As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

DTLBranchValue = "D:\Adryan Work\Project Sales Progress\DTL_SI_BRANCH_VALUE_crosstab.xlsx"
GetData DTLBranchValue, "DTL_SI_BRANCH_VALUE_crosstab", "C4:JO93", Sheets("Detail Value All Brand").Range("C19:JO108"), False, False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I used technique to  do it  in here [How to copy data from closed workbooks(keeping them closed) into master workbook using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310458/how-to-copy-data-from-closed-workbookskeeping-them-closed-into-master-workbook)

It can only copy from other workbook which it has ".xlsx" format. If I want to copy from ".CSV file", I need to open that workbook so the code can run. How can I copy  from ".CSV" file without open that workbook?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635526/return-csv-file-as-recordset - might not work if you are running Excel 64-bit