# VBA code to return specific record (row and column) within "recordset"

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 excel workbooks and and I am pulling data (A1:C5)from one (WB1) to another without opening the source WB using below Macro. I need to filter the data while it is in the recordset before pasting it to the target workbook.
The filter is that to delete any record = "No" in column "C"
how can I do that ?
Below is the code I am using:

```
Sub TransferData___()
   Dim sourceFile As Variant
   sourceFile = "C:\WB1.xlsx"
   GetData sourceFile, "Sheet1", "A1:C5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub

Public Sub GetData(sourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range)
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long

' Create the connection string.
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect                    'here the file is opened in the background
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1       'read data

TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it a recordset, or a "recordset" ?

Comment: are both the same ?

Comment: Why did you put it in quotes?  That suggests it's not an actual recordset.  Anyway, you're going to need to show a little bit of effort (and preferably some of your existing code) or your question is likely to be closed.  Did you google the properties of ADO recordsets?  `AbsolutePosition` seems like a good candidate here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/absoluteposition-property-ado

Comment: I am sorry Tim. I am not very experienced in VBA and I just wanted to highlight that Recordset is VBA term.
Thank you for the link. I will check it

Comment: Actually I am using the code from a question in below link. however, I want to manipulate the recordset before pasting it the target.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310458/how-to-copy-data-from-closed-workbookskeeping-them-closed-into-master-workbook?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: OK but in order to get any help you're going to need to post your own code and explain (1) exactly what you need to do and (2) exactly what problem you're having

Comment: Actually the code is very long (I got it from question#29310458).
I only need to delete some records from the recordset before pasting to the target cell based on specific critria.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I have read the article above but I could not find the answer.
"Recordset.field(#).name" returns the header's name. What is the code that returns specific records (row, column)

Comment: Did you try using `AbsolutePosition`?  I'm done here unless you're willing to post the relevant code and add some more detail to your question.  If you just need to delete some records have you considered instead filtering them out in your SQL?

Comment: I added the code I am currently using.
I think my question is straight forward and doesn't need further details.
My code is in VBA not SQL. Please me to know the exact Syntax for AbsolutePosition.

Comment: @YasserAboSameh your question is a bit unclear. You say you want to msgbox a value that is at position `row 3, column 2`... I'm assuming of the `adodb.recordset` that is returned from the query. Can you confirm? Also you mention here in the comments a completely unrelated request of "I need to delete some records from the recordset before pasting...". that sounds like a separate question. Can you please clarify, in your question, exactly what you are trying to do so that we can answer it. Both of these questions are completely doable. Also, when replying to comments please use @ reply.

Comment: @JNevill
I will completely restructure my question to clarify exactly what I want to do.
Thank you JNevill

Comment: @Tim: I have problem that not only records with "No" are deleted but all string records while numbers records are kept. this happen even before incorporate your code. How can I solve it ?
Note: it seems that the field type is deemed as a number so all string records are not considered. what code to add to change the field type to string ?
should I add this as a new question ?

Answer (score 0):

It's more typical to just exclude the unwanted records in your select statement:

```
szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "] where F3<>'No'"
```

F1, F2, F3, etc are the default field names if the data being queried has no header row.

Comment: Tim: I have problem that not only records with "No" are deleted but all string records while numbers records are kept. this happen even before incorporate your code. How can I solve it ?
Note: it seems that the field type is deemed as a number so all string records are not considered. what code to add to change the field type to string ?
should I add this as a new question ?

Comment: I would start a new question since this is a different issue.  Share the code again and it would be useful to include some sample data, or share a file with the data so people can reproduce your problem.